# I'm trying to calculate GPA using Sqlite database but it's only getting one course grade from the database, not all courses

Tags: c#

I am trying to build a University system and in this method, I'm trying to calculate GPA  using Sqlite database that contains all needed information[this is the table of the student](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXGuf.png) but it's only getting  one course grade from the database, not all courses

```
public double GpaCal()
        {
            connect();
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("select count(courseCode) from " + student + " where term = '" + termInfo + "';", myConnection);
            command.Connection = myConnection;

            int numberOfCourses = 0;

            numberOfCourses = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());

            string[] Subject = new string[numberOfCourses];
            double[] Marks = new double[numberOfCourses];
            double[] credithours = new double[numberOfCourses];
            double[] TGPA = new double[numberOfCourses];

            command.CommandText = "select * from " + student + "  where term = '" + termInfo 
            + "';";
            SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
            {

               

                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCourses; i++)
                {
```

I think the problem is here

```
                   
                    Grades = (double)reader.GetDouble("grade");
                    Marks[i] = Grades;
                    ECTS = (int)(long)reader.GetDouble("ECTS");
                    credithours[i] = ECTS;
```

here is the method to convert the grade into GPA:

```
                    if (Marks[i] >= 90 && Marks[i] <= 100)
                    {
                        TGPA[i] = 4.00 * credithours[i];
                    }
                    else if (Marks[i] >= 85 && Marks[i] <= 89.99)
                    {
                        TGPA[i] = 3.50 * credithours[i];
                    }
                    else if (Marks[i] >= 80 && Marks[i] <= 84.99)
                    {
                        TGPA[i] = 3.00 * credithours[i];
                    }
                    else if (Marks[i] >= 75 && Marks[i] <= 79.99)
                    {
                        TGPA[i] = 2.50 * credithours[i];
                    }
                    else if (Marks[i] >= 70 && Marks[i] <= 74.99)
                    {
                        TGPA[i] = 2.00 * credithours[i];
                    }
                    else if (Marks[i] >= 65 && Marks[i] <= 69.99)
                    {
                        TGPA[i] = 1.50 * credithours[i];
                    }
                    else if (Marks[i] >= 60 && Marks[i] <= 64.99)
                    {
                        TGPA[i] = 1.00 * credithours[i];
                    }
                    else if (Marks[i] >= 50 && Marks[i] <= 59.99)
                    {
                        TGPA[i] = 0.50 * credithours[i];
                    }
                    else if (Marks[i] > 0.00 && Marks[i] <= 49.99)
                    {
                        TGPA[i] = 0.00 * credithours[i];
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }

                }

                double GPA = 0;
                double TC = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCourses; i++)
                {
                    GPA = GPA + TGPA[i];
                    TC = TC + credithours[i];
                    ClassGpa = GPA / TC ;
                }
               
                return ClassGpa;
            }
            return 0.00;
            
        }
```

Comment: What is the value of termInfo and student?

Comment: You don't need the first query to count the number of courses and you don't need the `for` loop. Every call to `reader.Read()` will return another row, and each row is a separate course. Change your arrays to `List<string>` (or `double` as appropriate) and just add a value each time you read another row.

Answer (score 0):

**Now it's working this is the code:**

1. **student** in the SQL command is the table of the student who signed in
2. **termInfo** is the student's current term or previous term so I can calculate GPA for a specific term

```
 public double GpaCal()
        {
            connect();
            

      
            double[] Marks = new double[3];
            double[] credithours = new double[3];
            double[] TGPA = new double[3];

            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand ("select grade,ECTS from " + student + "  where term = '" + 3 + "';", myConnection);
            SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            int i = 0;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
               
                Grades = (double)reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("grade"));
                Marks[i] = Grades;
                ECTS = (int)(long)reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("ECTS"));
                credithours[i] = ECTS;
                i++;


            }
                    for (int j= 0; j < 3; j++)
                    {
                        if (Marks[j] >= 90 && Marks[j] <= 100)
                    {
                        TGPA[j] = 4.00 * credithours[j];
                    }
                    else if (Marks[j] >= 85 && Marks[j] <= 89.99)
                    {
                        TGPA[j] = 3.50 * credithours[j];
                    }
                    else if (Marks[j] >= 80 && Marks[j] <= 84.99)
                    {
                        TGPA[j] = 3.00 * credithours[j];
                    }
                    else if (Marks[j] >= 75 && Marks[j] <= 79.99)
                    {
                        TGPA[j] = 2.50 * credithours[j];
                    }
                    else if (Marks[j] >= 70 && Marks[j] <= 74.99)
                    {
                        TGPA[j] = 2.00 * credithours[j];
                    }
                    else if (Marks[j] >= 65 && Marks[j] <= 69.99)
                    {
                        TGPA[j] = 1.50 * credithours[j];
                    }
                    else if (Marks[j] >= 60 && Marks[j] <= 64.99)
                    {
                        TGPA[j] = 1.00 * credithours[j];
                    }
                    else if (Marks[j] >= 50 && Marks[j] <= 59.99)
                    {
                        TGPA[j] = 0.50 * credithours[j];
                    }
                    else if (Marks[j] > 0.00 && Marks[j] <= 49.99)
                    {
                        TGPA[j] = 0.00 * credithours[j];
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }

                }
                double GPA = 0;
                double TC = 0;
                for (int x = 0;x < 3; x++)
                {
                    GPA = GPA + TGPA[x];
                    TC = TC + credithours[x];
                    ClassGpa = GPA / TC ;
                }
               
                return ClassGpa;
         
            
        }
```